# Resolution is broken when converting byte to image?

Tags: c#, bitmap, byte

[image]

This is what happens when I load my project file into my software. This happens when I convert the 'byte' parameter into image again.

Here's my conversion method:

```
public Bitmap ConverToImage(byte[] ImageByteArray)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ImageByteArray))
        {
            return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
```

**Pushing the byte into an object of the ImageClass**

```
var image = new LayerClass
                        {
                            rect = l.rect,
                            image = img.ConverToImage(l.imageByte),
                            type = (LayerClass.Type)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(LayerClass.Type), "Image"),
                        };
```

Help.

Comment: The answer is no `Resolution is broken when converting byte to image?` does not process or change your image in anyway, however what you do with it how you display it may lead you to this conclusion

Comment: @TheGeneral I updated the question, that is how I use the byte into loading the image

Comment: Define "resolution is broken". What exactly are we seeing here? What is the problem?

Comment: the distorted picture in the bottom left should be a ribbon @CodeCaster

Comment: The problem probably is in how you _save_ the image. Looks like transparency isn't supported by the format you chose.

Comment: @CodeCaster I save it from image to byte then loads it the opposite way. What could go wrong?

Comment: `Image.FromStream` **requires the stream to remain open for the life time of the image**. Meaning, you can't put it in a `using` block and return the image; you'll return an already-corrupted image. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610796/picture-is-used-by-another-process-layoutpanel/49623930#49623930) a basic list of things to keep in mind when handling images.